# Flashing a C program to ARM

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I just started programming for an ARM Processor and I have never been this clueless. There are a couple of example projects that came with the board (ADucm350) and I wanted to upload one of them. I downloaded Keil (or I think it's just the project management software part of it) and got armcc. I compiled all of the files with armcc on command prompt. But then I got a bunch of errors

```
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 588: Error:  #1114: this feature not supported on target architecture/processor
          register uint32_t __regBasePri         __ASM("basepri");
                                                       ^
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 594: Error:  #1114: this feature not supported on target architecture/processor
          register uint32_t __regBasePri         __ASM("basepri");
                                                       ^
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 594: Warning:  #550-D: variable "__regBasePri" was set but never used
          register uint32_t __regBasePri         __ASM("basepri");
                            ^
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 600: Error:  #1114: this feature not supported on target architecture/processor
          register uint32_t __regPriMask         __ASM("primask");
                                                       ^
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 606: Error:  #1114: this feature not supported on target architecture/processor
          register uint32_t __regPriMask         __ASM("primask");
                                                       ^
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 606: Warning:  #550-D: variable "__regPriMask" was set but never used
          register uint32_t __regPriMask         __ASM("primask");
                            ^
    "C:\AnalogDevices\ADuCM350BBCZ\Eval-ADUCM350EBZ\inc\core_cm3.h", line 612: Error:  #1114: this feature not
```

I believe these errors make sense since I am not connected to an ARM device. How do I emulate the ARM environment and flash the program to the board. I do not have Keil or IAR but I do have JLink (if that helps).

Can someone guide me to some tutorial? I am really lost :|

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling for the correct platform/processor? Those errors look like some instructions are used that aren't supported by the processor that you are compiling for.

Comment: Just note, that it has nothing to do with flashing. These are compiler errors.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: How about editing the title so that it reflects the question asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before compiling, you need to configure your target architecture, so that the compiler knows what type of device it is compiling code for.  There are many different ARM architectures, with various code capabilities.

You might want to check KEIL for an appropriate "Getting Started" guide.

Here is one to start with:  http://www.keil.com/product/brochures/uv4.pdf

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I got to compile the project and now should be able to flash it on to the board. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad that was the information you needed.